# How to validate if the Google Plus profile exists?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus, profile

I have combined  Admin SDK Directory API with the Google+ Domains API to fetch all the Google plus profile  information.

But , There are people who do not have Google Plus profile in our organization which generates a null pointer Exception,I also tried  the below code to validate

```
            Person profile = plus.people().get(directorylist.getId()).execute();


            if(!profile.isEmpty())
            {


            System.out.println(profile.getDisplayName());

            profile.getImage().getUrl();
            profile.getSkills();
            System.out.println("SKILL="+profile.getSkills());
            System.out.println("ORG="+profile.getOrganizations());
            }
```

But the validation is not working and it is throwing null pointer Exception . Let me know if anyone has a better solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
public abstract boolean isPlusUser()
```

[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#isPlusUser())

Comment: This will not work because   the exception is on first line                                         profile = plus.people().get(test.getId()).execute();
  
  if(profile.getIsPlusUser()!=null)
  {
   System.out.println("SKILL="+ profile.getImage().getUrl());
         
         System.out.println("SKILL="+profile.getSkills());
          
        
         
  }

Comment: You want `isPlusUser` not `getIsPlusUser` and it returns a boolean so `!= null` is not the right test.